# Auto completion of code is not working inside cardview tags

Tags: android, android-cardview

I am using Cardview inside linear layout. As soon as I type in Cardview tags any further code in the limits of the Cardview tags does not complete automatically on typing...I.e auto suggestions feature is not working. But if I type the whole code manually (which is a tedious task BTW) then no errors are shown. So can anybody suggest why auto suggestions are not loading up?

Answer (score 0):

name spaces may not be correct see below. I also use CardView as the rootview.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:focusable="true"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">


</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you point out what is not correct or where the difference is?

Comment: Specifically xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"